# Error al mostrar preview de imagen en angularjs con css

Tags: css, angularjs

Estoy trabajando con ng-file-upload para trabajar con imagenes. En si tengo dos opciones para subir una imagen para cada una. Al mostrar la primera imagen se muestra en mi primer ng-model pero al mostrar mi segunda imagen en mi segundo ng-model éste no se muestro sino que se sobre escribe mi primer ng-model. A continuacion comparto mi vista html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m12 hide-on-med-and-down">
      <div class="image-upload">
        <label for="file-input">
          <i class="material-icons left teal-text">photo_camera</i>
          Agrega imagen 1...
        </label>
        <input
          id="file-input"
          type="file"
          ngf-select
          ng-model="data.imagen_promocion"
          name="file"
          ngf-pattern="'image/*'"
          accept="image/*"
          ngf-max-size="3MB"
        />
      </div>
      <img ngf-thumbnail="data.imagen_promocion || '/thumb.jpg'"/>
    </div> 
    <div class="col s12 m12 hide-on-med-and-down">
      <div class="image-upload">
        <label for="file-input">
          <i class="material-icons left teal-text">photo_camera</i>
          Agrega imagen 2...
        </label>
        <input
          id="file-input"
          type="file"
          ngf-select
          ng-model="data.imagen_promocion2"
          name="file"
          ngf-pattern="'image/*'"
          accept="image/*"
          ngf-max-size="3MB"
        />
      </div>
      <img ngf-thumbnail="data.imagen_promocion2 || '/thumb.jpg'"/>
    </div> 
  </div>
```

El error esta en mi css

```
.image-upload > input{
  display: none;
}
.image-upload i{
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Si borro este css mi codigo trabaja de forma correcta. este es mi [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dimoreno/yjgafc33/7/) 
Como puedo solucionar este error?
de antemano les agradezco

Comment: ¿Haz probado utilizar valores `name` diferentes en los `inputs` veo que ambos tienen el mismo valor `file`?

Comment: si pero igual falla

Comment: En los ejemplos de ng-file-upload veo que se utiliza el atributo ngf-multiple en un botón o bien en un área donde se sueltan los archivos. Sin embargo no que utilices este atributo en tu código.

Comment: @JuanManuel dices que agregue ngf-multiple?

Comment: Sinceramente nunca usé `ng-file-upload`, pero en la página https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload veo que los ejemplos en lugar de usar `input` se usa `button`  para seleccionar el archivo o un `div` donde se puede arrastrar y soltar. Luego supongo que `ng-file-upload` se encarga de crear el `input` correspondiente por tí. Yo te recomiendo que tomes un ejemplo de subida múltiple tal como lo escribe el desarrollador y luego lo adaptes a tus necesidades.

Comment: Aquí tienes dos ejemplos: Upload multiple files one by one on file select: http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/2vq88rfs/136/ y Upload multiple files in one request on file select: http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/huhjo9jm/5/

Comment: @JuanManuel ya se cual es mi error, está en mi css ahora actualizo mi pregunta este es mi jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dimoreno/yjgafc33/7/

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que los ids y los names de los inputs son iguales y el atributo for de cada label apunta al mismo input. Aquí tienes el ejemplo que funciona: https://jsfiddle.net/d6jb2817/